# How to Dynamically Set Column Link in Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I solved my original problem in a different manner because I couldn't find out how to set column links dynamically in time, but I am still curious on how this could be done.  We can statically set the f?p= link for a column in the Report Attribute/Column Link page and include #Column_templates#, and then Oracle will set the hyperlinks for that column.

Is this capability exposed to developers ?

Is there a JQuery/hack to get this done ?

Comment: Can you add an example of an sql statement?

Comment: @Tom I clarified it a bit. The main report will return either one or more business keys, an effective date, and one or more attributes. 90% of the time there is only one business key; 10% of the time there are multiple busisness keys. The other attributes consist of a semi-obscure string: a combination of a staging table's value and the data warehouse's corresponding table's value. The purpose of the secondary report is to clarify the semi-obscure string, and it does this by selecting the value of the attributes from both tables (where clause being the BK/EFFDT) and then placing them in union.

Comment: Umph - that still sounds complex! The column links are links in the primary report, and will actually redirect to the same page and set the value of some page items. The secondary report is conditional, and will now show because the items are filled in and will show its results. Thus, what you're asking is for the column link in the primary report to set the page items with varying values (columns) depending on a certain condition. Correct?

Comment: I actually solved this problem in a different way (by creating an item and then statically setting the hyperlink to set that item to a concatenation of every column; and then using PL/SQL to sort out if it is a business key or an effective date ....) but I am still interested in how to dynamically adjust column links. In the column link page for a column, APEX lets us set a link with column templates #xx# and then it gets to work. How does it do this? I wonder if there is something we can pass a f?p= link and a column to and have it set the columns on the fly.

Comment: Not really. The column header substitution strings only work right then and there. It doesn't give you plenty of wiggling room. I'd honestly think that the best way to do this would be constructing your link in your query, and then you could create a column link on this value.

Comment: @Tom Ok. What do you mean by constructing a link in a query?

Comment: Since you're already putting out the sql through a procedure, it may not be too hard to include an extra column which concatenates the correct values, instead of trying to force this through javascript.